# CPP running external program, wait until it finishes and return the retcode

Tags: c++

Okay, as a part of my Lib i need a 'Worker' application to run an external program.
Normally i would do it with a call to:

```
system("");
```

But this time what is needed is:

- Return code of that program
- Application to work while the executed program is running

So a pseudocode would look like this in perfect implementation:

```
CTask::Run()
{
   m_iReturnCode = -1;

   ExecuteTask(m_strBinaryName);

   while(Task_Executing)
   {
     HeartBeat();
   }

   return m_iReturnCode;
}
```

Just to clarify, i am running this on *Unix* platforms.

What are my options here, popen / fork ?
Anyone having a good solution already running and can shed a bit of light on this please?

Thanks for any input into this.

Comment: You might want to either fork it or run the task in separate thread.

Comment: I was having that in mind, will wait for more suggestions to see what else can be done here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a linux system, boost for threading and a pipe to execute the command and get its result (if you do not know [boost](http://www.boost.org) you certainly should have a look at it).

I found the hint to use a pipe here on stackoverflow but I am sorry I do not know the exact question any more.

I do not add the outside thread code. Just start the method `execute` within its own thread.

```
std::string execute()
{   
std::string result;

// DO NOT INTERRUPT THREAD WHILE READING FROM PIPE
boost::this_thread::disable_interruption di;

// add echo of exit code to command to get the exit code
std::string command = mp_command + "; echo $?";

// open pipe, execute command and read input from pipe
FILE* pipe = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
if (pipe)
{
    char buffer[128];
    while (!feof(pipe))
    {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
        {
            std::string currBuffer(buffer);
            result += currBuffer;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    mp_isValid = false;
}

// sleeping busy wait for the pipe to close
while (pclose(pipe) == -1)
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: Now that sounds like a plan!
Perfect!

Comment: That looks like $nix only, what about Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a fork with fork() (or clone() if you want threads), and then run the program using execve() or system() in one process, and continue running the original program in the other.

For the return code, you can get the return code even from `system()` call as :

```
ret = system("<your_command>");
printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(ret));
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be some sort of interprocess or interthread communication. In case you don't want to fork it or use threads, you can try using a shared file. Open the file for writing in the child task (called by `system()`) and when you are done, write some value (e.g. "finished") and close the file. In the parent task, heartbeat until you read "finished" from the shared file.

You can do this also by writing a global variable instead of shared file.

However, I would fort or thread it, using a shared file or global variable is error-prone and I am not entirely sure it would work that way.